# Comparing multiple row and columns in sql server

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, compare

I had two tables first one is the real table second one is the  temporary. I had to compare this two table . First table had 'KartelaKod' field should match with temp's 'KartelaKodu' field, First's 'OzellikKod' field should match with temp's 'OzellikKodu',first's 'AltKod' field should match with temp's 'StokKodu'.
[image: Tables]

Finally if it doesn't match exactly it should return ''.

PS: You should have to group first table according to VrtUrunKod.
In example if MAM|002's (which is VrtUrunKod) OzellikKod field doesn't match with temp table's OzellikKodu field, it should look for another VrtUrunKod record.

Edit1:`isnull((Select TOP 1 VrtUrunKod From KonfigOlusmusOzellikler k Where Sirket_Kod = @sp_Sirket_Kod and AnaUrunKod = @spStokKod and
                     exists(Select * From #TempDegisen t Where t.KartelaKodu = k.KartelaKodu and t.OzellikKodu = k.OzellikKod and t.StokKodu = k.AltKod)),'')` this is what i written so far you can ignore Sirket_Kod field and parameter.

Comment: Can you post the SQL you've written so far?

Comment: I added my query. But of course this is wrong this is just returns me only one row comparing.

Comment: Starting to misunderstand your question, i think.. Do you want a single row result that describes if the two tables are matched, or do you want a list of all rows that don't match?

Comment: Im just using "KonfigOlusmusOzellikler" as a data pool which i can filter.

Answer (score 0):

This should produce a list of rows where there is a k with no matching t, and at with no matching k. If no rows result, all rows are matched:

```
SELECT *

FROM 
  KonfigOlusmusOzellikler k
  FULL OUTER JOIN
  #TempDegisen t
  ON 
    t.KartelaKodu = k.KartelaKodu and 
    t.OzellikKodu = k.OzellikKod and 
    t.StokKodu = k.AltKod

WHERE t.KartelaKodu IS NULL OR k.KartelaKodu IS NULL
```